# jquery is not outputting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i am trying to output something from a php file with jquery.. the php file contains a if else statement and im able to output what is in the if part, but when the logic goes to the else part nothing is outputed. im getting confused.

here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitNewExam').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newExam = $('#newExam').val();
        if ($.trim(newExam) != ''){
            $.post('functions/addExam.php', { newExam: newExam }, function(data){
                $('#notify').html(data);
                $('.alert').toggle();
            });
        }
        $('.add').toggle();
    });
});
```

and the php code:

```
include ('resources/addExamClass.php');
if(isset($_POST['newExam'])){
    if(preg_match('/(<|>|"|%3c|%3e|%22)/', $_POST['newExam'])){
        echo "illegal characters found !!!";
    } else {
        $newExam = new addExam();
        $newExam->CQuiz($_POST['newExam']);
        echo "correct";
    }
}
```

if the preg_match match i can see in the developer tools/network that there is 200 ok and jquery gets the response.
if preg_match doesnt macth i can see a 302 and then 404.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: I don't know if that's the error, but try to not use the same name for a data field and a variable.

Comment: it says this: GET http://localhost/examProj/functions/main.php 404

Comment: why check for `!= ''` and `isset`, and also why check for `<`,`>`, and `"` and their URI encoded equivalents? jquery should encode that, anyway. try commenting out your `preg_match` and replace it with false, and see if you still get nothing.

Comment: i dont understand why the path is being changed, the real location of main.php is this:  localhost/examProj/main.php

Comment: well i checking for <,> " to prevent Xss. because the content will be stored in a database.

Comment: You're not querying main.php, you're looking at addExam.php. Do you see any data returned from that?

Comment: yeah i can see the data returning from the if part, but the else doesnt return.

Comment: Just encode the data coming through the pipe. this will prevent the html from hitting your backend.

Comment: i have to enconde with json???

Comment: @eg_dac i encoded with json_encode and is still the same.. is hitting the backend like you said.

Comment: using php you want to encode it before processing the data. JS should only be used for client side. If i turn js off, it won't get encoded. Never trust data coming in as you probably already know. Read this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: PHP error reporting is active? Maybe there's an error in `addExamClass` that ajax output is not showing, and the execution stops before the `echo "correct"`. Try to use `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` or `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before the if/else to show any possible errors.

Comment: there is no error with the php class. it is a redirecting problem which im still trying to understand. the path for the main.php is: localhost/examProj/main.php... after i run the jquery and the data is sent to the php the path becomes localhost/examProj/functions/main.php. this is why i dont get the response.

Comment: the main.php file contains the jquery code. this file lives in the root of the webpage. the addExam.php is in the functions folder, and within this folder is the resources folder where the addExamClass.php is.

Comment: btw, the class is doing his job which is storing the information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, Use the php urlencode, and you won't need to worry too much about preg_match. Just set the incoming vars like

`$name = urlencode($_POST["name"]);`

Also check your php variables and make sure warnings / errors are turned on to display. You might be returning an error and not seeing it.

Comment: ok i think i found where the problem is, i thought this part of the code was not important but it is the reason why is hitting the backend. i going to edit my main post for you to see.

Comment: the reason im hitting the backend is because of the class im using in the php file.